# How to convert element's Table to List / Array to make an independent multivariable fit?

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, fitting

I would like to make an independent multivariable fit, but I have problems using a Table that I generated. I can´t use their elements because it isn´t in a list or a rectangular array.

**Using Table[ ] to generate data**

I want to make a kind of fit, for data that I got from a numerical solved integral. To get this multiple results I used `Table[ ]`, by iterating. In this example I have table´s elements with three components.

```
data = Table[{i, j, 
    NIntegrate[((i^2)*
        j) (-Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] - 
         Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ])/((i^2)*(Cos[ϕ] - 
              Cos[θ])^2 + (i^2)*(Sin[ϕ] - 
              Sin[θ])^2 + (j^2))^(3/2), {θ, 0, 
      2 π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", 
     AccuracyGoal -> 10]}, {i, 0.01, 1, 0.01}, {j, 0.2, 1, 0.01}];
ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]
```

**Making a Fit**

I was writing the following code based on examples in this forum and Mathematica documentation. I was hoping that my data generated with `Table[ ]` runs well.

```
model = -a (x/y)^2; 
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a}, {x, y}] 
Show[Plot3D[model /. fit, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPointPlot3D[data, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]]
```

But after second line I get:

```
FindFit::fitd: First argument {{{0.01,0.2,-0.000365534},{0.01,0.21,-0.000301072},{0.01,0.22,-0.000250202},<<5>>,{0.01,0.28,-0.0000957317},{0.01,0.29,-0.0000832305},<<71>>},<<9>>,<<90>>} in FindFit is not a list or a rectangular array.
```

For this reason I'm looking for how to make this format conversion. `Grid[ ]` doesn´t work. I've been watching examples where using data generated with `MapThreat[ ]` it works, and I ask again, how to convert my data got with `Table[ ]` to `MapThreat[ ]`?

**How to do it using a function?**

I think that an alternative way is use a function, but i don´t have idea how to implement this in fit´s code.

```
h[i_, j_] := 
  NIntegrate[((i^2)*j) (-Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ] - 
       Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ])/((i^2)*(Cos[ϕ] - 
            Cos[θ])^2 + (i^2)*(Sin[ϕ] - 
            Sin[θ])^2 + (j^2))^(3/2), {θ, 0, 
    2 π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10];
```

I apologize if this question is trivial, I was looking for information but I can´t make it works. Thank you for read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fit using `FindFit` it is better not to take too much points. The error message tells us, that one needs to `Flatten`your nested list. Try this:

```
data = Flatten[
  Table[{i, j, 
    NIntegrate[((i^2)*
        j) (-Cos[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]] - 
         Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]])/((i^2)*(Cos[\[Phi]] - 
              Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (i^2)*(Sin[\[Phi]] - 
              Sin[\[Theta]])^2 + (j^2))^(3/2), {\[Theta], 0, 
      2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", 
     AccuracyGoal -> 10]}, {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}, {j, 0.1, 1, 0.1}], 1];


model = -a*(x/y)^2;
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a}, {x, y}]
Show[Plot3D[model /. fit, {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 1}, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPointPlot3D[data, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]]

(*  {a -> 1.79013}  *)
```

[image]

I recommend changing your model a bit:

```
Manipulate[
 model = -a*(x/y)^c + b;
 fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, b}, {x, y}];
 Show[Plot3D[model /. fit, {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All], 
  ListPointPlot3D[data, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]], {{c, 1.038}, 0.5,
   1.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

and play with the parameter `c` a bit. It returns the following

[image]

Very nice. Let me add that after you have found a suitable value of `c` you can find its finer value using `FindFit` as follows:

```
model = -a*(x/y)^c + b;
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, b, {c, 1.038}}, {x, y}]
Show[Plot3D[model /. fit, {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 1}, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPointPlot3D[data, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red]]]

(*  {a -> 9.34242, b -> 1.86593, c -> 1.20022}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Wow! I have no words to express how grateful I am, thank you. Thanks for not ignoring my question even though there was a simple solution, I was looking for it for a long time, but I think I would never find the function `Flatten[ ]`.  And your last recommendation it was far from my point of view about how to use Mathematica, is fantastic, blow my mind, i will use this approaching in the future.